# question about else statement...blackjack in python

Tags: python, blackjack

Python newbie here.  I'm trying to create a black jack game in which the user plays against the computer. I think where I'm having trouble is with the if, elif statements here.  What I want to know is, what happens when none of the criteria of any of the if and elif statements are met when I don't have an else statement?  Is it problematic here not to have an else statement?

```
def game_winner(n):

    p_wins = 0
    d_wins = 0

    for i in range(n):

        player_sum = player_game()
        dealer_sum = dealer_game()

        if player_sum > dealer_sum and player_sum <= 21:
            p_wins = p_wins + 1

        elif dealer_sum > 21 and player_sum <= 21:
            p_wins = p_wins + 1

        elif player_sum > 21 and dealer_sum <= 21:
            d_wins = d_wins + 1

        elif dealer_sum > player_sum and dealer_sum <= 21:
            d_wins = d_wins + 1

    return p_wins, d_wins
```

Comment: srry wrongly edited...please revert back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the conditions are met then none of the conditionals in any of the `if` or `elif` blocks are executed. If it is ok that neither the computer or the player wins in a round, then it's fine. Otherwise you should include an `else` statement to cover that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an else, the code will simply "fall through"; i.e. none of the conditional code will be executed, so the win counts will not be changed.

Looking at the specifics of your example, the only potential problem I see is that there will be some games that aren't counted.  Your requirements or design will determine if this is really a problem or not.

Comment: right, so if none of conditional code is executed, will the loop just iterate over again?

Comment: correct - neither win counter will be incremented and the next round will execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid. Having no else statement isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    rng = xrange   # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    rng = range    # Python 3.x

def game_winner(n):
    p_wins, d_wins = 0, 0
    for i in rng(n):
        player = player_game()
        if player > 21:
            d_wins += 1
        else:
            dealer = dealer_game()
            if player <= dealer <= 21:
                d_wins += 1
            else:
                p_wins += 1
    return p_wins, d_wins
```